# Is there a way to view a slideshow with OpenOffice Impress with a video embedded beneath the slide content?

Tags: video, openoffice, slideshow, openoffice-impress, embedding

I have a video clip I want to add slideshow content in order to gussy it up before producing it, but when I add the clip to OpenOffice.org's Impress software, the video always plays on top of all the slideshow content, even if I send it to be the background element. If I can run a slideshow while the video is running, beneath it, i can record that with Fraps and have my slideshow enhanced video clip. Is there any way to achieve this functionality?